# Does a unit cell have to contain a whole number of atoms?

Tags: crystal-structure, solid-state-chemistry, crystallography, lattices

I was given this problem recently to compute the number of ions in a unit cell of ferrous oxide $\ce{FeO}$. The data given was:

> Side length $a = \pu{5 Å}$
>
> Density $d = \pu{4 g/cc}$

Using the formula $\displaystyle d = \frac {ZM}{N_0 a^3}$, I obtained $Z = 4.18$. However, the answer had rounded $Z$ off to $4.$

**Could a unit cell have  a fractional number of atoms**? Intuitively, it doesn't make sense for a cell to have $0.18$ of an atom. If, by experimental analysis, we obtain a fractional number of atoms in a unit cell, do we round them down as is done in this problem?

P.S. Another thought would be that such odd numbers are obtained due to stoichiometric defects.

Comment: 1. $Z \in \mathbb{N}$ (always, by the definition of the number of formula units); 2. Both $a$ and $d$ are given to the single significant figure. How did you manage to obtain the more precise answer with three significant figures using this data?

Comment: @andselisk: Would you please elaborate your comment as an answer to the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Crystallographic background

A [unit cell](https://dictionary.iucr.org/Unit_cell) cannot contain parts of atoms from a formula unit, otherwise it would not be a geometric unit of repeatability.
The simplest condition arising from translational symmetry is that the total number of atoms present in the unit cell must be either equal to or be a multiple of the number of atoms in the chemical formula, which is an equivalent to the integer number of formula units per unit cell: $Z \in \mathbb{N}.$

Note, however, that the [asymmetric unit](https://dictionary.iucr.org/Asymmetric_unit) (crystallographically independent region) contains the $Z/n$th part of the atoms of the formula unit, where $n$ is the order of the crystallographic point group.
Thus, the asymmetric region may contain an integer number of formula units, one formula unit or *its fractional part*, meaning that some atoms located on symmetry elements, are "divided" across several asymmetric regions.

#### Data precision

It appears you are using the correct formula for the crystallographic density $ρ$ (I strongly encourage not to use $d$ as a symbol for density as in crystallography $d$ is reserved for spacing between planes):

$$ρ = \frac{MZ}{N_\mathrm{A}V}$$

where $M$ is molar mass, $N_\mathrm{A}$ is Avogadro's number and $V$ is the unit cell volume.
Although you can use the exact value for $N_\mathrm{A} = \pu{6.02214076E23 mol-1}$ and a precise tabulated value $M(\ce{FeO}) = \pu{71.844 g mol-1},$ note that you are given both $a$ and $d$ (experimental data) to the *single significant figure*, which prohibits your answer from being more precise than these parameters, and you must present a rounded number $Z = 4$ and not $Z = 4.18,$ which doesn't make either crystallographic or mathematical sense.

In real life situation there always will be a systematic difference between the measured and crystallographic densities due to the presence of defects, and the deviation of $Z$ from the integer value is often due to statistically filling of the proper point group by the atoms of a different kind.

Comment: The density presented by andselisk is the one based on the diffraction experiment and the subsequently built model (`_exptl_crystal_density_diffrn` in the `.cif` files you find in databases, https://www.iucr.org/__data/iucr/cifdic_html/1/cif_core.dic/Iexptl_crystal_density_diffrn.html).  You should at least check by an estimation, if this density is reasonable.  The same files _may_ include an entry about `_exptl_crystal_density_meas`, measured e.g., by floatation of your sample in liquids (https://www.iucr.org/__data/iucr/cifdic_html/1/cif_core.dic/Iexptl_crystal_density_meas.html).